# Euler Problem 48 in Java - Converting to BigInteger

Tags: java

I attempted to input BigInteger but am having conversion problems and unsure how to find a better way to input this into my loops.

**The Euler question asks**
The series, 11 + 22 + 33 + ... + 1010 = 10405071317.

Find the last ten digits of the series, 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... + 1000^1000.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Montes_Euler4{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Problem 48

        long product;
        long newProduct = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i <=1000; i++){
            product = (long) Math.pow(i,i);

            for(int j = 0; j < 1; j++){

                newProduct = product + newProduct;
                BigInteger value = BigInteger.valueOf(newProduct);
                System.out.println("Here is the overall product! " + value );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you asked to print last 10 digits of final result, you need to think - how different positions affect each other, for example 12345*12345 - if you need to print only last 1 digit, you don't have to perform full multiplication, it is enough to multiple only last digits (5), so I can be sure that last digit of this multiplication is 5 and don't care about the rest, the same goes for addition

Comment: The expression `Math.pow(999, 999)` isn't going to be accurate enough to express the last 10 digits accurately, so this strategy is not going to work for you.  You could try doing all the calculations with `BigInteger` instead, but I'm not sure how well this will perform.

Comment: The point of these exercises is usually to find an alternative to the obvious method and solving in a certain amount of allotted time.  One way obvious attempt would be using a loop to sum the series.  The not so obvious method, if one exists, is to find the sum of a series by manipulating the terms and representing the entire series in a simpler form.  A typical example would be the partial sum of a geometric series of a fixed number of terms.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints for using `BigInteger`.

- You are computing a sum so initialize sum to `BigInteger.ZERO`.
- to add you need to do `sum = sum.add(Some bigInteger here).`
- to compute a power do `BigInteger result = myBigInt.pow(exp)` where `exp` is a `long`.
- to find the last 10 digits use the `BigInteger.mod` method

BigInteger values are immutable so you need to assign results to a BigInteger.  And you can chain operations.

```
BigInteger v = BigInteger.valueOf(23).pow(3).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(10));
System.out.println(v);
```

prints

```
7
```

Which is the last digit of `23^3` where `'^'` is exponentiation.